# Unable to create FIFO queue with dead letter queue in same cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I have a cloudformation stack containing a FIFO queue, and its associated dead letter queue. Previously this was not a FIFO queue, and it deployed fine, the dead letter queue dependency was made first, then the "source queue". After switching it to FIFO, it no longer works. I get this error:

```
"Template error: SQSQueue https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1234/dev-assignments-dlq doesn't exist",
```

So it seems the dead letter queue is no longer being created first.

```
 AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
    Resources:
      SourceQueue:
        Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
        Properties:
          FifoQueue: true
          QueueName: 'dev-push-notifications.fifo'
          RedrivePolicy:
            deadLetterTargetArn:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - 'DeadLetterQueue'
                - 'Arn'
            maxReceiveCount: 5
          VisibilityTimeout: 30
      DeadLetterQueue:
        Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
        Properties:
          QueueName: 'dev-push-notifications-dlq'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that the dead letter queue must be of the same type as its source.

Changing the cloudformation stack to this worked:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  SourceQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      FifoQueue: true
      QueueName: 'dev-push-notifications.fifo'
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - 'DeadLetterQueue'
            - 'Arn'
        maxReceiveCount: 5
      VisibilityTimeout: 30
  DeadLetterQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      FifoQueue: true
      QueueName: 'dev-push-notifications-dlq.fifo'
```

Answer (score 2):

That's weird, as Cloudformation should detect the dependency because of the `GetAtt`. You can try declaring it explicitly using the [`DependsOn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html) attribute:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
  Resources:
    SourceQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      DependsOn: DeadLetterQueue
      Properties:
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't end up working, but by forcing the dlq to be created first w/ DependsOn I got an error message that revealed the true cause:

"Dead-letter queue must be same type of queue as the source".

See my answer below.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad it helped and thanks for sharing the cause - I learnt something new.